# Apache: how to LogFormat original query string before is rewritten

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have mod_rewrite in place and working fine so `/screens/myScreen/myAction?id=123` gets rewritten as (roughly) `/actions/screen.php?scr=myScreen&cmd=myAction&id=123`

I'm trying to customize apache logs so they include only the stuff I really need in an easy to parse format. I'd like to log the original url path (/screens/myScreen/myAction) and the original query string (id=123).

I've tried the options I found in the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html):

**%U** works great and logs `/screens/myScreen/myAction`

But **%q**, instead of logging `?id=123` as I'd expect, is logging `?scr=myScreen&cmd=myAction&id=123` (the query string **after** being rewritten instead of the original one).

The closest I found was **%r**, but it includes the method, the protocol and everything together like `GET /screens/myScreen/myAction?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Is there a way of getting just the original `id=123`?

In case it matters, this is the rewrite rule I'm using:

```
RewriteRule  ^screens/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /fx/actions/screen.php?_scr=$1&_cmd=$2 [QSA,L]
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this today and I think I've found it.

[From the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html)

> The modifiers "<" and ">" can be used for requests that have been internally redirected to choose whether the original or final (respectively) request should be consulted.

Answer: `%<q`

Testing various options:

```
COLUMN 1                                  COLUMN 2                COLUMN 3                               COLUMN 4                                  COLUMN 5          COLUMN 6          COLUMN 7
%r: [GET /nothing.php?key=val HTTP/1.1]   %U: [/nothing.php]      %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING}e: [key=val]   %{REQUEST_URI}e: [/nothing.php?key=val]   %q: [?code=404]   %>q: [?code=404]   %<q: [?key=val]
%r: [GET / HTTP/1.1]                      %U: [/index.html]       %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING}e: [-]         %{REQUEST_URI}e: [-]                      %q: []            %>q: []            %<q: []
%r: [GET /common/.css HTTP/1.1]           %U: [/common/.css]      %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING}e: [-]         %{REQUEST_URI}e: [-]                      %q: []            %>q: []            %<q: []
%r: [GET /custom/.css HTTP/1.1]           %U: [/custom/.css]      %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING}e: [-]         %{REQUEST_URI}e: [-]                      %q: []            %>q: []            %<q: []
%r: [GET /background.jpg HTTP/1.1]        %U: [/background.jpg]   %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING}e: [-]         %{REQUEST_URI}e: [/background.jpg]        %q: [?code=404]   %>q: [?code=404]   %<q: []
%r: [GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1]           %U: [/favicon.ico]      %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING}e: [-]         %{REQUEST_URI}e: [-]                      %q: []            %>q: []            %<q: []
```

- Column 1, 2 and 5 you are familiar with already.
- Column 3 *would* be great as a separate column, but doesn't squish up to `%U` well without a `?`. One could be hardcoded, but then for requests without a query you'd see `/file.ext?-` which is ugly.
- Column 4 is great for requests that have query parameters, but fails completely if there are none.
- Column 6 seems to match column 5.
- Column 7 is on the money.

Therefore, `%U%<q`, or in my case, `%{Host}i%U%<q` because I want to see which domain name was used as I have several pointing to the same site.